# WP advanced custom fields Field Group have limit fields?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created a layout module 7m (layouts). Each layout has about 15-20 fields (including eating and one repeater with fields). There comes a moment when I can not create more fields. And nothing else is stored. A begins to persist if you remove one field. Then another one I can keep.

How can I fix this problem?

Change (screen http://awesomescreenshot.com/08835dz3eb )

But dont work

This is a complete number of fields that can be added (if you add one more), nothing happens. New fields do not appear.

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f635h2s43

44 filds (all including repeater ) in 7 Layout
I really need to solve this problem. I need at least another 10 fields.

Comment: did you try increasing max_input_vars?

Answer (score 3):

Few solutions you can try..

1. Increase `max_input_vars` value from 3000 to 5000 or more.. (it worked for me after increasing value)
2. This method is if increasing max_input_vars does not help..

Quoted from ACF forum :

“I had the same problem and it turned out that because the server was using the Suhosin patch I also needed to set the following my .htaccess file:

`suhosin.post.max_vars = 20000`

`suhosin.request.max_vars = 20000`″

Comment: max_input_vars 6000   in php.ini (end in .htaccess  suhosin.post.max_vars = 20000 suhosin.request.max_vars = 20000 )   to no avail

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem yesterday. I solve this by increasing value of **Blog pages show at most** and **Syndication feeds show the most recent** in **Setting -> Reading -> Heres the option**.

In my WP dashboard, the default is 10.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Rahul, 'max_input_vars' and suhosin settings in php.ini are the solution.

But what I would like to add to make this solution complete. You could get into case when migrating to other server or vps, where default setting for "max_input_vars" is 1000 or less and then You try to add new field which will result in all fields that was not in limit to disappear as from AFC administration or from POSTS also! .

So even if you fix the php.ini that leaves you with broken db.

Anyways solution is simple after setting 'max_input_vars' **move that ACF field group to Trash, and restore it** fields will be back ...

I hope it will save time to someone sometime.